# compare labels matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi when using a classifier in matlab (naive bayes) is there a method in which you can compare the classified labels to the original labels?

For instance take the image below, im manually having to go through each row and check which one it classified correctly and which one it didnt.

[image]

I was hoping for a list like Classified 550 smurf missclassified 50 and then it outputs another file with the idx of those rows misclassified.

Quick table of what it might look like

```
       Corrrectly Classified  |  Missclassified

Smruf        550                      50
Neptune      100                      80
and so on...
```

And then the index misclassified for Smruf

Smurf missclassified (row index)

```
4896 
456
12789
12
456
```

Rince and complete for the other misclassified labels.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the `confusionmat` function. Let's generate some sample data.

```
>> y = [repmat(1,100,1); repmat(2,100,1); repmat(3,100,1)];
```

And "classify" it

```
>> yhat = randsample(y,300); # randomly shuffle the inputs to 'classify' them
```

Now you call `confusionmat`

```
>> [c order] = confusionmat(y,yhat)
ans =
    37    35    28
    30    32    38
    33    33    34
```

The way to interpret this table is that row *r* and column *c* tells you the number of data points from class *r* that were classified as class *c*.

That is, the *diagonal* elements are the ones that are correctly classified, and the *nondiagonal* elements are incorrectly classified.

The variable `c` contains this matrix. The variable `order` contains the names of your classes, in the same order as they appear in the confusion matrix (i.e. you can intepret them as column headings).

In my example I classified points randomly, which is why I have so many misclassified examples.

Comment: Hey Chris I already use the confusion matric but its horrid, in my question it is much easyier to read and understand, the confusion matrix takes a book to learn how to interpret.

Comment: Just write a utility function that converts a confusion matrix into the form you want. Then you only need to interpret it once (and the interpretation isn't so hard). If `c` is your confusion matrix, then something like `N=size(c,1); for i=1:N; correct(i)=c(i,i); incorrect(i)=sum(c,2)-correct(i); end` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're classifying really huge datasets, a simple for-loop should be fine.

```
num_correct = 0;
num_wrong = 0;
for i=1:length(target_class)
    if isequal(taget_class{i}, class{i})
        num_correct = num_correct + 1;
    else
        num_wrong = num_wrong + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Hey Isaac thats quite elegant but what about determining the index?

Comment: You could just throw `indices[count] = i; count = count + 1;` into the `if`-statement you care about.